# Rails - Not saving child object if "where" or scopes are used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to change a child object and if I use scopes or where to filter it, the change isn't saved when I call .save on the parent object.

```
object = Object.find(@id)
object.children.where(active: true).each do |c|
   c.active = false
end 
object.save
```

like this, the object isn't saved, but if I do this:

```
object = Object.find(@id)
object.children.each do |c|
   c.active = false if c.active == true
end 
object.save
```

it works properly, what am I doing wrong?

Ruby v2.4.5p335

Rails v5.2.3

@Edit

Working: 
[image]
Not Working: 
[image]

Comment: I can't check right now, but try printing out (`p`) the variable `c` in both cases, maybe you find out why.

Comment: I tried it, in both cases the attribute is changed on `c` object.

Comment: Does using `assign_attribute(:active, false)` help?

Comment: same result sadly, it isn't saved

Comment: By the way, does your code have `if c.active = true` or `if c.active == true`?

Comment: rather than updating the children and saving the parent try `update_all(active: false)` e.g. `object.children.where(active: true).update_all(active: false)`. This will avoid all callbacks, validations, and model instantiation as well as being far more efficient

Comment: ops, my mistake, it's `if c.active == true`
@engineersmnky that would work, but I can't do that, since I need to run the validations on the parent model before doing so and also run the same code when it's a new object being created

Comment: Can you share the logs? Do you see any `Rollback` in there?

Comment: @xSlok if your are validating the parent are you sure the validation is not failing? The code posted just shows that you call `save` but does not show that the return value is `true` generally one would save `if object.save` to ensure that save actually worked. If the `object.save` is failing the cascading saves would not occur.

Comment: in both cases the `.save` returns true, prints of the running code added to the question

Comment: Try the following `object.includes(:children).where('children.active' => true).each..`

Comment: tried it, same result sadly

Comment: The issue is as you stated due to the fact that `where.` is going to created a clone of Relation ("spawn") thus appears to disconnect it from `object`. I have no idea what the purpose of this code is as it is unclear in this context so it is difficult to propose alternative solutions.

Comment: the child object in this case is a `join table` that binds `table 1` and `table 2`, and this join table has an `active` attribute, that defines the state of the relation between them. I need to set `active` to false when a `table 2` id is not in a specific list, and save it to database when I save the parent object.